# Definition of $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic graph

Tags: graph-theory

I see a definition of a planar, bipartite $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic graph, which is a graph can be embedded in the plane, the vertices can be coloured by white and black such that every edges of the graph has exactly one white vertex and one black vertex, and all the translations act by colour-preserving isomorphisms, i.e. the isomorphisms which map white vertices to white ones and black vertices to black ones.

I don't understand the last condition. Someone can explain clearly?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that, in the case $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic graphs, we only consider those graph-isomorphisms which preserve vertex colour to be a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic-graph-isomorphism. For instance, consider the graph $G$ which looks like $\bullet-\circ$ With black vertex $b$ and white vertex $w$.

The map $f\colon G\rightarrow G$ which maps $b\mapsto w$,$w\mapsto b$ is a graph isomorphism, but it is not a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic-graph-isomorphism because it does not preserve vertex colour. In the case of $G$, the only $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic-graph-isomorphism is the identity map.

Let $G'$ be the graph which looks like $\bullet-\circ -\bullet$ With black vertices $b_1, b_2$ and white vertex $w$. In this case, the map $f'\colon G'\rightarrow G'$ which maps $b_1\mapsto b_2$, $b_2\mapsto b_1$, $w\mapsto w$ is both a graph isomorphism **and** a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic-graph-isomorphism because it does preserve vertex colour.

For a more complex example, Consider the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ and colour the vertex $(a,b)$ black if $a+b$ is even, and white if $a+b$ is odd - this is the classic checkerboard colouring of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Add an edge between $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ if $a+1=a'$ or $b+1=b'$ and not both $a+1=a'$ and $b+1=b'$. We note that  this defines a planar bipartite $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic graph $G$. Consider the map $t\colon G''\rightarrow G''$ defined by $t(a,b)=(a+1,b)$. This is a graph isomorphism but is clearly not colour preserving. On the other hand, the map $t'\colon G''\rightarrow G''$ defined by $t'(a,b)=(a+1,b+1)$ **is** colour preserving and so it is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic-graph-isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. I think I understand your answer, except one point I am still confused: What dou you mean when you say $\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic-graph-isomorphism?

Comment: It's the kind of isomorphism that the author is considering. By definition, it's an isomorphism which also preserves vertex colour. I just called it that to distinguish it from a normal graph isomorphism. Thinking about it, maybe I should have called them *colour-preserving isomorphisms* instead.

Comment: So by your answer, in such graph ($\mathbb{Z}_2$-periodic graph), we only consider graph isomorphisms which preserve colours of vertices. In this case, how does it concern to $\mathbb{Z}_2$? I mean what is the role of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ here? Can we replace $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by another group?

Comment: I assume (you would really have to check the source you're using) that these are called $\mathbb{Z}^2$-periodic graphs  because there is a $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action defined on the collection of all such graphs which takes a coloured graph to the same graph but swaps colours at each vertex. Presumably, using $n$-coloured graphs, such a graph would be called a $\Sigma_n$-periodic graph as $\Sigma_n$ (the symmetric group on $n$ elements) acts on the collection of such coloured graphs by permuting the colours. (I'm not a graph theorist so this is at best a guess).

Comment: @ Daniel Rust : Thanks a lot! I will check my paper.